# Relationship between strong and weak operator topologies

Tags: operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, weak-convergence, strong-convergence

I am looking for citations in a book or article for the following fact:

Let $T_n$ be a sequence of operators in Hilbert space and $T$ also be an operator in Hilbert space.
If $T_n$ is convergent in a weak operator topology to $T$ and $T_n^*T_n$ is also convergent in a weak operator topology to $T^*T$, then $T_n$ is convergent in a strong operator topology to $T$.

Answer (score 3):

$\def\Re{\operatorname{Re}}$ It's a rather straightforward computation:
\begin{align}
\|T_nx-Tx\|^2
&=\|T_nx\|^2+\|Tx\|^2-2\Re\langle T_nx,Tx\rangle\\[0.2cm]
&=\langle T_n^*T_nx,x\rangle+\|Tx\|^2-2\Re\langle T_nx,Tx\rangle\\[0.2cm]
&\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}\langle T^*Tx,x\rangle+\|Tx\|^2-2\Re\langle Tx,Tx\rangle\\[0.2cm]
&=\|Tx\|^2+\|Tx\|^2-2\|Tx\|^2=0. 
\end{align}

Comment: yes, I know, I'm just looking for a citation

Comment: I expect that in most texts this will be left as an exercise.

Comment: I looked for various books by authors such as Rudin, Douglas, Diximier, Murphy, but I couldn't find this fact anywhere.

Comment: Yes, this result is  both very specific and very simple, so it is not very likely to be recorded explicitly.